# Replace Value based on Value Before

Tags: r

I have a tibble with variables that use '99' or '999' as a conglomeration of all values above the value before.  How would I change that to the value before + 2.

Example below.

```
level <- c(1,2,3,4,99)
variable <- c('age', 'age','age','age','age')
value <- c(.5, .75, 1, 1.25, 1.89)
d <- data.frame(Variable = variable, Level = level, value = value)
```

I would like to end up with

```
Variable     Level     Value
age          1         .5
age          2         .75
age          3         1
age          4         1.25
age          6         1.89
```

I'm not even sure where to start in picking the value before the 99 based on the condition that the starting value is 99.

Maybe

```
d$Level <- if(d$Level = 99, nrow(-1) + 2, d$Level)
```

Comment: What do you want the level to be if the first row has 99/999? In my current solution it would become NA, and 2 in user2974951's case.

Comment: Maybe this works too : `inds <- which(d$Level == 99);
d$Level[inds] <- d$Level[inds - 1] + 2 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new vector with lagged values

```
temp=c(0,d$Level[1:(length(d$Level)-1)])+2
d$Level=ifelse(d$Level==99,temp,d$Level)
```

Answer (score 3):

I  would use `data.table::shift()`:

```
with(d, ifelse(Level %in% c(99, 999), shift(Level) + 2, Level))
[1] 1 2 3 4 6
```

But to do this in `base R` you could define a helper function:

```
baseShiftBy1 <- function(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)])
with(d, ifelse(Level %in% c(99, 999), baseShiftBy1(Level) + 2, Level))
```